# Why is parquet record conversion with Kinesis Datafirehose creating None column in created parquet file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I'm trying to use record conversion from JSON to parquet with Kinesis Data Firehose but the resulting parquet is creating a column of None like below:

```
   payload
0     None
1     None
2     None
```

Here is the data that is being passed into the firehose from my transformation lambda...

```
{
  mainid: {
    id1: 'org-sam-test-2-glue-schema-org',
    id2: '9dbcf7d824b821e968983e2f040918d64f75bd331ff8442265c56c13cc6d8be8',
    id3: 'f8676ed6-188a-488b-aff2-32b1d51cec51',
    id4: '36fd2a6e-81e1-4516-810f-74e8adbb8ba1',
    id5: 'b30a3bf1-999f-4a07-b15b-c7cc29d33df9',
    id6: '9dbcf7d824b821e968983e2f040918d64f75bd331ff8442265c56c13cc6d8be8'
  }
}
```

This is my glue table schema that creates a "payload" column in the resulting parquet.

`struct<mainid:struct<id1:string,id2:string,id3:string,id4:string,id5:string,id6:string>>`

Here is my KDF set up,

[image]

Does anyone know how to get my parquet column correctly serialised?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone doing something similar... the glue schema should be written as

```
[
  {
    "Name": "mainid",
    "Type": "struct<id1:string,id2:string,id3:string,id4:string,id5:string,id6:string>",
    "Comment": ""
  }
]
```